# Get Apple's remote push notifications even after app terminates

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, background-process, uiapplicationdelegate

I am developing an iOS app which receives apple's remote push notifications at a particular time interval. The notifications are received successfully when app is active as well as when app is in background. But when app is terminated from app switcher/dock, notifications are not received until the app is started again.

I have tried following code to keep app alive in background. This same code is implemented in `applicationWillTerminate:` method, but it did not work.

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask ;
    UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        [app enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
```

What is the perfect way of receiving notifications even after app is terminated?

Comment: If you specify remote-notifications background mode then iOS will re-launch your app when a remote notification is received **unless** your app is terminated from the switcher, in which case they assume that the user does not want your app to run and so your app will not be re-launched until the user launches your app manually

Comment: This is against the design by Apple, I don't think you should waste time and effort doing that.

Comment: Sounds like you want silent notifications that open you app to allow processing https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you actively stop the app in the app switcher it stops receiving any push notifications.

This is an intended behaviour as stated by Apple engineers in the developer forums.

Comment: Yes true, I have understood this behaviour now. Thank you. :)

Comment: Has this change? I have been reading some answers that implies what @kevin griesbach has said is correct, but when i test it with a brand new app and houston, i can recieve notification even after i explicitly stop the app in the app switcher

https://github.com/nomad/houston