# Gcm not sended to apn when iOS app was killed

Tags: ios, iphone, google-cloud-messaging

Gcm send to apn when foreground and background. <- send ok

But if Force Quit Application, gcm not sended to apn. <- send not ok

When Force Quit Application, apn is possible send notification because, "APN Tester" is send notification Available.

< test condition >

iPhone 4

7.1.2

object c code(GcmExample.app)

use curl

```
< curl --header "Authorization: key=$server_api_key" \
--header Content-Type:"application/json" \
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send \
-d "{\"data\":{\"title\":\"title\"},\"notification\":{\"body\":\"noti test\",\"content_available\":true},\"to\":\"$token\"}" >
```

< etc use >

`"GcmServerDemo"` tool

`"APN Tester"` tool

Comment: If your app is terminated from app switcher, then your app wont get push notifications. You can see [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26141776/4195406)

Comment: According to the test results , I tried , after a forced shutdown application , the "APN Tester" can deliver a notification .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try a message that has `high APNS priority` e.g.

```
 curl --header "Authorization: key=$server_api_key" \
      --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
      https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send \
      -d "{
         'data': { 'title': 'title' }, \
         'notification': {'body': 'notitest' }, \
         'content_available': true, \
         'to': '$token', \
         'priority': 10,
      }"
```

You need to set the `priority` explicitly to `10` else GCM assumes normal APNS priority which can get highly delayed.

[Here is the GCM reference](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) where you can read about the `priority` field.