# Handling Push Notification on iOS 10.3 or newer when the app is terminated

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios11, ios10.3

I want to find out which method is triggered when a terminated application receives a notification from my server. The application is being developed through Swift 4, my Deployment Target is 10.3 and Firebase is used to send notifications to users.

I've configured my application in AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

}
```

Additionally, I created the extension:

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    }
}
```

When the app receives a notification and it's running or it's in background, the method "willPresent" is called and when the user taps on the notification and decide to open it, the method "didReceive" is called. No method is triggered if the application is terminated.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Apple's remote push notifications even after app terminates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176066/get-apples-remote-push-notifications-even-after-app-terminates)